# NullPointerException on Button when extending base activity

Tags: android

I have an activity, which is a `NavigationDrawer` Activity and am having another activity extend this activity. When I start this child activity, I get the famous `java.lang.NullPointerException`

```
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.testapp.ShopActivity.onCreate(ShopActivity.java:23)
```

I don't see why this is happening since I have done everything the right way in my `onCreate()` method.My full ShopActivity class code:

```
public class ShopActivity extends BaseDrawerActivity {



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Button navButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.nav);

   navButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { //<-Line 23
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), BaseDrawerActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

}

 @Override
public int getLayoutResourceId() {
    return R.layout.activity_shop;
}

}
```

Not sure why this is happening.Without the button, `ShopActivity` works fine and has a navigation drawer, same as the one in `BaseDrawerActivity`. I have tried implementing `OnClickListener` but I get the same error

**EDIT**

This is the content of the `oncreate()` method of the `BaseDrawerActivity`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_base_drawer);

    mNavigationDrawerFragment = (NavigationDrawerFragment)
            getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.navigation_drawer);
    mTitle = getTitle();

    // Set up the drawer.
    mNavigationDrawerFragment.setUp(
            R.id.navigation_drawer,
            (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout));
}
```

if I change `setContentView(R.layout.activity_base_drawer);` I start getting the same error on `navigationDrawerFragment`

Comment: Better check if navButton is null.

Comment: I'm not positive about this, but maybe try Button navButton = (Button) super.findViewById(R.id.nav);

Comment: Are you sure you use setContentView method? Seems like u don't inflate anything.

Comment: @ethan123 tried that, still getting the error

Comment: @Kaerdan I didn't use that because I already have a method that handles that `public int getLayoutResourceId() {
        return R.layout.activity_shop;
    }`

Answer (score 0):

navButton is null. You're never loading a layout. Or maybe you're doing it in BaseDrawerActivity but then your button isn't in the layout or has a different id.

Comment: But I have a method that loads my layout.If I add `setContentView` to my onCreate method, the app crashes.To load the layout, am using `public int getLayoutResourceId() {
        return R.layout.activity_shop;
    }`

Comment: Done that.If i use `setContentVIew(R.layout.activity_shop)` it crashes when I start the activity with  `No view found for id...`

Comment: Please read [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it) which is likely to help you determine if your object is null.

Answer (score 0):

As other people mentioned your `navButton` is `null`. The most likely cause is that you are not calling `setContentView()`. Unless in the onCreate method your super calss of `BaseDrawerActivity` you have `setContentView(getLayoutResourceId())`, this is the reason.

To solve this problem, you need show the onCreate method of your super class `BaseDrawerActivity`. Without this, not much further can be said.

Also, post the content of `activity_shop.xml`.

Comment: If I use `setContentView(getLayoutResourceId())` in `BaseDrawerActivity` I get the  same error am getting here in that class.